# Is it possible to use custom public transport line with Here routing service

Tags: here-api, location-based-service, here-maps-rest

We need to have a complement on public transportation services, so we need to input theses lines so that they will be considered together with the official public transit layers when invoking the routing Api in Here.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your application the following ways: 
1. Inorder to insert new connections you can use Custom Route Extension API. It provides numerous usecase including
Enable roads - Customer can open certain road links for their fleet, because their vehicles have special permissions.
Using the above api you can have your own links to destinations and use the Transit API under it to get public transport information and link it to your route. 
2. If you are providing a transport service on existing roads in Here map then you need Intermodal Routing API. Your usecase is like any cab service which can be combined with other transport modes.

You can read more about the above two approaches in Here Developer site. Happy Coding!